# SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby

Tags: java, netbeans, derby

I've found this question before but non of the answers work for me!
I've got this error after running:

> SQLException: No suitable driver found for
>   jdbc:derby://localhost:1527//RIHANNA-PC/Users/javadb

I've add derbyclient.jar to Library.but I didn't get any different result.I also don't want to create a new database.

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    String userid="a", password = "a";

 //   "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527//RIHANNA-PC/Users/javadb"
    String url = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527//RIHANNA-PC/Users/javadb";
    Statement stmt;
    Connection con;
    String createString="select * from tbl_operator where user_id='" + jTextField1.getText() +  "' and pwd='" + jTextField2.getText() + "'";
    ResultSet rs;
    try {
        con=DriverManager.getConnection(url,userid, password);
        stmt = con.createStatement();
        rs=stmt.executeQuery(createString);
```

Comment: Code sample would be nice, may point us/you in the correct direction.

Comment: Do you have a Class.forName() statement to register the ClientDriver with DriverManager? That shouldn't be necessary if you're running JDK 6, but also can't hurt. Another thing to try is to run the 'sysinfo' tool with your application's classpath to see what sysinfo reports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you load Derby JDBC driver? You can do it using the following java startup command:

```
java -Djdbc.drivers=org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver
```

For another way to load it see docs: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.7/devguide/cdevdvlp40653.html

Comment: just added a link to Derby doc which explains loading JDBC driver.

Comment: "If your application runs on JDK 6 or higher, you do not need to explicitly load the EmbeddedDriver. In that environment, the driver loads automatically." I'm running JDK 6!!!

Comment: Note that if your url is jdbc:derby://localhost:1527//RIHANNA-PC/Users/javadb, then you are NOT running the EmbeddedDriver; you are running the ClientDriver. So these instructions for the embedded driver may not be what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same question.
If you want to connect the javadb by netwrok,you should be startNetworkServer,and create the database in this status.

And the driver is "org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"